# Closed subset in different norms

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, lp-spaces

Let us say I have a space of functions $X$ (e.g. $X=C([0,1],[0,1])$ continuous from the unit interval into itself) and two subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $S_2\subset S_1(\subset X)$ (e.g. $S_i=L^i([0,1],[0,1])$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$). Suppose that $S_i$ is a Banach space under norm $\|\cdot\|_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ (e.g.$\|\cdot\|_i = \|\cdot\|_{L^i}$). Suppose that I give you any closed subset $A$ of $S_2$ (with the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm). Is this subset $A$ also closed in $S_1$  (with the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm)? My intuition tells me it is not, but I would appreciate a counterexample.

Comment: have you tried (counter)examples with Sobolev spaces?

Comment: I have not, are you only just suggesting or is this motivated by an intuition?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you should be able to find very simple counterexamples by considering $W^{k,2}\subset W^{h,2}$ for some $k> h\geq 1$...

Comment: You do not need complicated things like Sobolev spaces. Try $A=\ell^1\subseteq \ell^2$.

Comment: OK, so I would take the entire $\ell^1$ as my closed subset of $\ell^1$. Then, consider a sequence of elements in $\ell^1$ converging in $\|\cdot\|_{\ell^2}$-norm. I would be tempted to consider the sequence $\{\,\{\sum^j_{i=0}{\tfrac{1}{j}}^{1-1/n}\}^\infty_{j=0}\,\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, but unfortunately the limit in $\|\cdot\|_{\ell^2}$-norm is probably still in  $\ell^1$ since the limit probably is $\{\sum^j_{i=0}\tfrac{1}{j} \}^\infty_{j=0}$

Comment: I realised this question can be simplified: can you find a sequence of elements in $S_1$ converging in $S_2$ under the norm on $S_2$?

Comment: For any $x\in\ell^2\setminus\ell^1$ (e.g., $x_k=1/k$) consider the *truncated* sequences $x^n=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots)$. They belong to $\ell^1$ and converge to $x$ in $\ell^2$.